# Mathjax multi-line equation rendering issue in Stack Exchange

Tags: mathjax

I'm trying to ask a question in Quantum Computing using some inline equations and a multiline equation. However, I have problems rendering both:
[Rendering issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm20H.png)
The code I'm trying to render is the following:

```
By complete positivity of $\epsilon$, $\rho_\epsilon$ must be positive. Then, we can expand $\rho_\epsilon$ as follows: Choosing the basis $( |i \rangle )_{i=1}^d$ of $H_A$ and $(| \alpha \rangle )_{i=1}^d$ of $H_R$, we construct the bases $(| i \rangle \langle j|)_{i=1}^d$ of $B(H_A)$ and $(| \alpha \rangle \langle \beta |)_{i=1}^d$ of $B(H_B)$. Thus, we can express $\rho_\epsilon$ as
$$
\rho_\epsilon:=\sum_{i,j}^d \sum_{\alpha,\beta}^d (I_R\otimes\epsilon)(\sigma) |i\rangle\langle j| \otimes |\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|. \tag{3}
$$
By taking the trace of (3), we obtain
\begin{align}
Tr\left( \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d (I_R\otimes\epsilon)(\sigma) |i\rangle\langle j| \otimes |\alpha\rangle\langle \beta| \right) 
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d Tr((I_R\otimes\epsilon)(|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|) |i\rangle\langle j| \otimes |\alpha\rangle\langle \beta|) \tag{4.1} \\
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d Tr(|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega| |i\rangle\langle j| \otimes \epsilon(|\alpha\rangle\langle \beta|)) \tag{4.2} \\
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d \langle\Omega| |i\rangle\langle j| \otimes \epsilon(|\alpha\rangle\langle \beta|) |\Omega \rangle \tag{4.3} \\
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d \sum_{k,l}^d \overline{c_k}c_l \langle kk| |i\rangle\langle j| \otimes \epsilon(|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|) |ll\rangle \tag{4.4} \\
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d \sum_{k,l}^d \overline{c_k}c_l \langle k|i \rangle \langle j|l \rangle \langle k| \epsilon(|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|) |l\rangle \tag{4.4} \\
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d \sum_{k,l}^d \overline{c_k}c_l \delta_{ki} \delta_{jl} \langle k| \epsilon(|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|) |l\rangle \tag{4.5} \\
&= \sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}^d \overline{c_i}c_j \langle i| \epsilon(|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|) |j\rangle \tag{4.6}
\end{align}
```

On one side, the character "(" causes problems for rendering `$( |i \rangle )_{i=1}^d$`, so by deleting them, `$ |i\rangle_{i=1}^d$` renders fine. However, `| i \rangle \langle j|_{i=1}^d$` doesn't render; even if I just write `| i \rangle \langle j|$`, it doesn't work.

On the other hand, I have no clue what causes trouble rendering the multine equation. I tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008515/mathjax-rendering-issue) solutions with no success, that is, adding `\( \begin{align} ... \end{align} \)` or using `$...$`, as well as replacing parenthesis by `$\left(` and `$\right(`. However, as pointed out by @turtle in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860693/mathjax-multi-line-equation-rendering-issue), adding six escapes `\\\\\\` works fine. Such a solution leads me to a further concern, which is about how the equation is displayed to other people. Let me explain this further: While trying to find a solution, I decided to prove such code in Edge (I was originally working with Chrome), and since I typed `\\\\\\`, the multiline equation was too vertically separated. I corrected the code as shown above, with no rendering problems (in Edge), until now.

Therefore, my question is what can I do to make the posted code works.

**Solution**

As pointed out by Davide Cervone, using `\\\\` instead of `\\` and `\_` instead of `_` solves both rendering problems.

**Update**

When I posted my code, I got the wrong formatting of the inline equations:

[Wrong Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGLDw.png)

So I just deleted the backslash from `\_` and then the inline equations displayed correctly, even if they were not rendering fine. Also, the multiline equations were too vertically separated, so I changed `\\\\` to `\\` again.

I don't know why the rendering and the display do not coincide, though. In conclusion, my original code was right; the rendering in Stack Exchange wasn't working, but the display was fine.

**Another Update**

If I ask a new question and then copy the code above, I get the same problem:

[Rendering Issue up to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVOgd.png)

This seems like only a problem of mine, though.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333242/mathjax-does-not-allow-multi-row-in-line-math-on-github-pages/77338223#77338223).  The setting is different, but the issue is the same (how Markdown interacts with LaTeX notation, in particular the use of `_` in Markdown to introduce italics.  See my answer to that post.

Comment: PS, the MathJax implementation on StackExchange sites is supposed to handle this interaction properly, and I haven't seen this error on SE sites before.  But the code that underlies the editor has been changing, and it may be that the protection for the math expressions has been broken.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment! Indeed, your solution worked for the multiline equation. However, I still have problems with the inline equation, and I just noticed that `$(| i \rangle \langle j|)_{i=1}^d$` doesn't render even if I delete the parenthesis. I'll update that information.

Comment: Did you use `\_` instead of just `_`?  That is the key, as it is the underscores that are being interpreted by Markdown.

Comment: @DavideCervone After implementing your solution, the rendering after the post looked fine, but after posting, the equation is displayed in the wrong formatting.

Comment: When I copy your example post into the editor on Quantum Computing, it displays properly for me.  So something seems to be different about our situations.  Are you using a desktop or mobile device?  What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using a laptop with Windows 11, and the problem appeared for me in both Chrome and Edge browsers.